# fb.ui feed 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi everyone I have a `btnfb` which if you click the feed dialog appears and share on facebook.
But I having error on `fb.ui { link: }` giving me `error 500 internal server error`.

if `link` is `"http://localhost:3001/campaigns/tracker/123BCDSLKF"` the code is okay. But if the `link` is `http://localhost:3001/campaigns/tracker/"+tracker` -> which I made `dynamic` it giving me error.

```
$(function(){
                $('#btnfb').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var tracker = generate_tracker();
                    <?php $tracker = generateRandomString(); ?>
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'feed',
                        name: 'Test title',
                        link: "http://localhost:3001/campaigns/tracker/"+tracker,
                        picture: 'my_picture_link',
                        caption: 'Test caption',
                        description: 'test description',
                    }, requestCallback);
                });
            });
```

Tracker generator:

```
function generate_tracker(){
         var text = "";
         var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

         for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
             text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
          }

         return text;
     }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 is an internal page error. When you view the link in a browser does it 500? Also, the link that works only has a numeric tracker id, whereas your function is generating an alphanumeric string. Either way this appears to be unrelated to Facebook's sdk.

Comment: Yes it does, even alphanumeric works fine.. But when I tried to make it dynamic just like the code above it gives this error `POST https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed 500 (OK)`

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console to see if fb has logged any errors?

Comment: yes it gives me this error:
`POST https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed 500 (OK)`

Comment: just check your site url on FB app, may be you putted whole string with tracker over there, if yes then remove tracker from there.

Comment: my `site url` is `http://locahost/magento/`, the error is in the `link:"http://localhost:3001/campaigns/tracker/"+tracker,`

`FB.ui({
                        method: 'feed',
                        name: 'Test title',
                        link: "http://localhost:3001/campaigns/tracker/"+tracker,
                        picture: 'my_picture_link',
                        caption: 'Test caption',
                        description: 'test description',
                    }, requestCallback);`